Error on raspberry 3B+ when updating and installing opencv
I am a student in Vietnam, working on a project for my embedded course and encountered this error on raspberry 3B+, please help.)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I also did not run the following commands, and they all threw the same error as above:
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev 
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test


Stretch has not been fully supported for years. see e.g. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=356182#p2134511

FYI: only English is supported on Pi SE

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Stretch is obsolete and code has been moved to legacy.
It is recommended you use a more up-to-date OS (Bullseye).
There will NEVER be any updates, but if you are forced to use you can still download old code using in sources.list:-
deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib
